# How to change my working directory using "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh" in Jenkins?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, shell-script, jenkins

I put these commands inside the command field just to check if I am able to change my working directory..

pwd

cd /apps/working/agent/working_agent/ (Directory path to run my script)

pwd

However the output is

/home/rjmb

/home/rjmb (path after I change the directory)

so, no changes at all.. I have tried a lot of ways to change it, but I did not succeed.

it really doesn't change directory. .

Comment: What are you actually asking? What do you mean by "inside the field?"

Comment: Oh in Jenkins job under  build tab, there is an option where you can add a build and one of the options is "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh" . .After clicking that option, you will be required to put the ssh under the "SSH site"  and the command that you want to execute under the "Command" Field . .So I wonder why those unix commands that I have put in the field doesn't work at all . . I mean after executing those commands like changing directory, I am still in the the same directory . . But after a long hour of thinking hard stuffs, I have figured it out already. . .

Comment: It's insane ! man. I mean on that specific build option there is also a check box under the command field stating "Execute each line" - which I checked. So after a very long hour of thinking a good solution, I noticed that checkbox and tried to uncheck it, and it perfectly execute the commands . ..

Answer (score 0):

You should use quotes when launching multiple commands at once with ssh:

```
dodger@localterminal ~ % ssh dodger@ciberterminal.net "pwd ; cd /tmp ; pwd"
/home/dodger
/tmp
dodger@localterminal ~ %
```

single quotes will also work and allow you to use remote variables:

```
dodger@localterminal ~ % ssh dodger@ciberterminal.net 'pwd ; cd /tmp ; echo $PWD'
/home/dodger
/tmp
dodger@localterminal ~ %
```

Comment: Thanks @dodger , I really appreciate your help. In my case there is no need for me to put any double quote or single quote thing in my ssh as Jenkins already have this option in build tab called "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh" where I just need to filled in the "ssh site" for the ssh and  "command" for the commands that I wanted to execute.. And for the very long hour of thinking to what's really wrong, I have figured it out already. I just have to leave the checkbox "Execute each line" UNCHECK - and it does change the directory already . . I don't know why, but it does.